# Handle an event in derived class but also notify client when the event occurs

Tags: c#, events

I have a class that inherits from Button. The derived class must perform a task when the button is clicked but also needs to notify the client.  I handle the click in the derived class but I'm having trouble notifying the client.  This is where I am...

```
//declare delegate types for hooking up events.
public delegate void NextEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public new event NextEventHandler NextClick;

protected override void OnNextClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   m_BtnNext_Click(sender, e);
}

protected void m_BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PopulateGrid(Calc1stOfMonthDate(m_CurrentMonth).AddMonths(-1));
}
```

How can I both run PopulateGrid and notify the client when the button is clicked?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "notify the client"? Are you talking about a `MessageBox` or...?

Comment: I assume the OP means what ever handlers are listening to the event? Is this correct, Topher?

Comment: Why have you declared your own delegate type which is identical to `EventHandler`? Why are you creating a second event rather than just subscribing to the first one? What is `NextClick` anyway? (Compared with just the `Click` event...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about...

```
protected override void OnNextClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    // check for any listeners...
    if(NextClick)
    {     
        NextClick(sender, e);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks...that lead me to a solution which was to subscribe to the button click event in the derived class then, as you suggested, raise the NextClick event, which I did from the button_click handler in the derived class.